# Initializing tables on spring boot startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, in which I need to initialize the tables based on some configuration. I am using managed transactions using `@Transactional`. My problem is that I do not know when app is ready to make DB transactions. 
I created a bean which reads the configuration and updates the tables, but it gets an exception at that point:

`Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`

I have tried that if I wait sprintboot to start and make the same transactions through HTTP requests, then there is no problem. So it seems to be a timing problem. I have also tried moving the code to `@PostConstruct` of bean but it does not fix the issue.

How can I know that app is ready for DB transactions? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest way of performing the initialization should be by making your bean implement ApplicationListener for ContextRefreshedEvent and then handling the initialization in the onApplicationEvent method. This way, your initialization will run when Spring's whole application context is initialized

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I actually used the annotation @EventListener which is available in spring 4.2 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen on some events Spring is publishing.
See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events)

You properbly need to listen on this even: ContextRefreshedEvent